# To find the matched and unmatched values in perl

Tags: perl

I am a newbie to programming and I hope someone can explain this to me:

So I have two text files i.e. Scan1.txt and Scan2.txt that are stored in my computer. Scan1.txt contains:

```
Tom
white
black
mark
john
ben
```

Scan2.txt contains:

```
bob
ben
white
gary
tom
black
patrick
```

I have to extract the matched values of these two files and the unmatched values and print them separately. I somehow found the solution for this which works fine. But can someone please explain how exactly the match happens here. Looks like somehow just this line:
`$hash{$matchline}++` in the code does the matching and increments the value of hash when the match is found. I understand the logic but I do not understand how this match actually happens. Can someone help me understand this?

Thank you in advance!

Here is the code:

````````````````````````
open (F1, "Scan1.txt");
open (F2, "Scan2.txt");

%hash=();

while ($matchline= <F1> ){ 
  $hash{$matchline}=1;
} 

close F1;

while( $matchline= <F2> ){ 
  $hash{$matchline}++;
}

close F2; 

foreach $matchline (keys %hash){
  if ($hash{$matchline} == 1){
    chomp($matchline);
    push(@unmatched, $matchline);
  }
  else{
    chomp($matchline);
    push (@matched, $matchline);
  }
}

 print "Matched Entries are >>\n";
 print "```````````````````````\n";
 print join ("\n", @matched) . "\n";
 print "```````````````````````\n";
 print "Unmatched Entries are >>\n";
 print "```````````````````````\n";
 print join ("\n", @unmatched) . "\n";
 print "```````````````````````\n";
````````````````````````

Answer (score 0):

The code you mention above will give you a false result if a given word exists more than one time in the second file and not exists in the first.

this line:
$hash{$matchline}++
increments a  different counter for each different word.

in the first loop it sets to 1 for the words in the first file.

so if a word exists in each file the counter will be at least 2.

the $hash itself is a set of counters.

Answer (score 0):

A more generalized version of your problem is that of computing the *set union or intersection* between two sets. This [link](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch04_09.htm) gives a very good treatment of the problem in general.

In your case, the set is nothing but the list of values from each file. The logic is, if a certain value was present in both files then $hash{matchline} == 2, because the value will be incremented in both the while loops. However, if the line was present in only one of the files, the value of $hash{matchline} == 1, since only one while loop will increment the value and not the other.

Also, Lajos Veres raises a very important point: if a certain word, say "Tom" is present twice in the same file, then the algorithm will fail. It is a subtle detail, which can be resolved in many ways- removing duplicates beforehand, using two hashes, etc.

Hope this helps.